# elements of UIScrollview doesnt start from 0,0

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, xib

[image: ----------]

I am having a weird problem....I am using Xcode 4.5.2 iOS sdk 6.0
i took a scrollview in XIB...i turned off the auto layout feature...I want to add a imageview(or any other UIView or its subclasses) at the position (0,0)...i can drag and drop the view to that position but in size inspector of XIB it shows weird data....it is showing in the picture that the position of the imageview is (160,303)..i tried to create new class with XIB but the problem is repeating again and again..thanks in advance if you have the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your origin is set to the bottom middle. Change it to top left

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check your `origin`, set it to `left top`

It should be

[image]

Hope it helps you